# volume & brightness control

Tags: brightness, volume-control

I have just installed ubuntu 11.10 oneiric on my dell studio 1569.
I am experiencing a strange problem with brightness control, volume control etc:
my hotkeys are enabled and, apparently, when I use them the indicator of volume and brightness changes. Same result when i manually change brightness and volume. But to the change in the indicator does not correspond any change in the effective brightness and volume.
Any idea about what can I do?

thanks a lot,
/matteo

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution at [this blog](http://linuxlike.blogspot.com/2011/06/como-ajustar-o-brilho-do-monitor-via.html) or [this one](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/brightness-indicator-for-ubuntu-unity.html)

> Excerpt from the answer at *[ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/brightness-indicator-for-ubuntu-unity.html)*
>
> - Install Brightness indicator on ubuntu
> - Download deb package from [here](http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128)  and install by double clicking on it.
> - After installing the package, add the program to your startup    programs:
>
>   - Run System Settings » Startup Applications » ‘Add’
>   - Name: `indicator-brightness`
>
>     Command:    `/opt/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness.py`
>
>     Comment: `optional`
>   - Click ‘Add’.
>
> Screenshot:
>
> [image: screenshot_of_app]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to a similar problem this way:

## Add the next option under your "Device" section in /etc/X11/xorg.conf and restart:

Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"

This worked for my NVIDIA card.